# Tomcat Tuckey UrlRewrite to rule issue

Tags: java, xml, tomcat, url-rewriting, tuckey-urlrewrite-filter

My problem is this, I have issues with similar looking rules in my urewrite.xml file, in the fact that the first rule will work, but similar rules that follow will not. Here is an example:

```
<rule>
<from>Porsche-911_991-3.4_Carrera.jsp</from>
<to>cars.jsp?makeID=640&amp;modelID=3747</to>
</rule>

<rule>
<from>Test-Porsche-911_991-3.4_Carrera.jsp</from>
<to>test.jsp?makeID=640&amp;modelID=3747</to>
</rule>
```

The first rule works, the second does not, the reason for which escapes me. If I manually visit test.jsp?makeID=640&modelID=3747 the page works, if I try Test-Porsche-911_991-3.4_Carrera.jsp the page does not appear, simply generates an error log specifying parameters are missing.

I hope somebody can assist me before I pull all my hair out.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The matching text of the first rule, `Porsche-911_991-3.4_Carrera.jsp`, is a substring of the matching text of the second rule. As a result, the second URL is gone.

Use the [caret metacharacter](http://urlrewritefilter.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/src/doc/manual/4.0/guide.html) to distinguish between the two URLs:

```
<rule>
  <from>^/Porsche-911_991-3.4_Carrera.jsp</from>
  <to>cars.jsp?makeID=640&amp;modelID=3747</to>
</rule>

<rule>
  <from>^/Test-Porsche-911_991-3.4_Carrera.jsp</from>
  <to>test.jsp?makeID=640&amp;modelID=3747</to>
</rule>
```

Reversing the order to put the more specific URL first would work as well:

```
<rule>
  <from>Test-Porsche-911_991-3.4_Carrera.jsp</from>
  <to>test.jsp?makeID=640&amp;modelID=3747</to>
</rule>

<rule>
  <from>Porsche-911_991-3.4_Carrera.jsp</from>
  <to>cars.jsp?makeID=640&amp;modelID=3747</to>
</rule>
```

Comment: I noticed that if you actually swap the word to the end before the .jsp then you can have both rules, so Porsche-911_991-3.4_Carrera-Test.jsp works, granted this is not ideal but the word Test is only for testing purposes. I will look into the use of caret metacharacter, thank you.

Comment: Since English reads from left-to-right, Carrera-Test.jsp is not a substring of Carrera.jsp, but Porsche is a substring of Test-Porsche. A [suffix tree](http://www.allisons.org/ll/AlgDS/Tree/Suffix/) may help visualize the relationship.